# SQL to make sure combined type having count(*) > 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), PERSON_ID
FROM 
    SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT SPAT(NOLOCK)
WHERE
    ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE IN ('ACTV','RFND')
GROUP BY 
    PERSON_ID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(PERSON_ID) > 1
```

Here I just want to make sure it should return the records count greater than one whose account status should be combination of any one 'ACTV' and 'RFND' status.

But if any of person Id has only "ACTV" of "RFND" status for more than one then it should not return.

Example :

person id 1100 has 2 accounts both are 'ACTV' status. person id 1200 has 2 accounts both are 'RFND' status. person id 1300 has 2 accounts having 'ACTV' and 'RFND' status.

My query should return only 1300 person id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE) as CT, PERSON_ID
FROM 
SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT SPAT(NOLOCK)
WHERE
ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE IN ('ACTV','RFND')
GROUP BY 
PERSON_ID 
HAVING 
COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE) > 1
```

**EDIT**

Here is proof, Using `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` doesn't change anything.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp

create table #temp ( PERSON_ID int, ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE varchar(20) null, SOMETHING varchar(6))

insert into #temp (PERSON_ID,ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE, SOMETHING) values
(1100,'ACTV','A'),
(1100,'ACTV','B'),
(1300,'ACTV','C'),
(1300,'RFND','D')

SELECT 
    COUNT(*), PERSON_ID
    FROM 
    #temp (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
    ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE IN ('ACTV','RFND')
    GROUP BY 
    PERSON_ID 
    HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all people with exactly one status value of each type:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID
FROM SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT
WHERE ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE = 'ACTV'
GROUP BY PERSON_ID 
HAVING COUNT(PERSON_ID) = 1  

INTERSECT

SELECT PERSON_ID
FROM SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT
WHERE ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE = 'RFND'
GROUP BY PERSON_ID 
HAVING COUNT(PERSON_ID) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE), PERSON_ID
FROM SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT SPAT(NOLOCK)
WHERE ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE IN ('ACTV','RFND') --this where clause might be optional according to my understanding
GROUP BY PERSON_ID 
HAVING COUNT(distinct ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE) > 1
```

Comment: maybe there are other ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUEs then just those two.  Then the WHERE is needed.

Comment: That's true so I included where in the query,

Comment: Though correct, this is a duplicate answer. In the future, please suggest other (new) ways of obtaining the OP's desired results such as @Hogan approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to identify which PERSON_ID's meet your criteria:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID
FROM SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE) > 1
```

If you need to get associated information along with their PERSON_ID:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SCT_PERSON_ACCOUNT
WHERE PERSON_ID IN (
    SELECT PERSON_ID
    FROM SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT
    GROUP BY PERSON_ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_STATUS_VALUE) > 1
    )
```